# JWT token not found 401

Tags: jwt, api-platform.com, symfony6

When I try to get JWT token with Symfony 6  / Api-plateform /  lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle  on the endpoint defined on my route.yaml

```
authentication_token:
    path: /api/login
    methods: ['POST']
```

The return of API is this :

```
{
    "code": 401,
    "message": "JWT Token not found"
}
```

The key was setting in my .env and the file of the key was already created.

security.yaml

```
main:
            stateless: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            json_login:
                check_path: /authentication_token
                username_path: email
                password_path: password
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            jwt: ~
```

I have checked if all the config files was present and if the jwt config key and files was created.

The endpoint was created and security.yaml if configured.

Comment: have you tried intercepting the request to check the headers? it seems that the Bearer header is missing

Comment: @SecurityObscurity When  I check the header I can see the Bearer  option : www-authenticate Bearer .

Comment: does it have a value? because 401 means that no JWT was passed

Comment: @SecurityObscurity Ok, I think I see the problem, I want to generate a JWT token for my user. So I can't pass anything that I don't have in my possession the goal being to identify my user email password and if there is a user I return a jwt token.

Comment: Okey I have solved the problem with this command : php bin/console lexik:jwt:generate-keypair --overwrite

Comment: You can post that as an answer for future reference!